# Border color change on no input

Tags: html, css

I have a code and I want, if there is no input, the border color is blue. I have this:

```
 <fieldset>
    <label>Number</label>
    <input type="number" value="1" max="10" min="1" step="1" required>
</fieldset>
```

and

```
input:out-of-range {
 border: solid red 1px;
 }
input[value=""] {
border: solid purple 1px;
}
```

**I want the number box to be purple when its empty**

Comment: Your code is already working Edzo.http://jsfiddle.net/no39s521/ or You want it on form submit?please clear this point

Comment: In JSfiddle it works, in that when there is no input, it shows a red border. Is the bit that isn't working the out of range bit?

Comment: I want that the number box shows a purple border when it's empty and not red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use an attribute selector in that way. Changing an `<input>`s value will modify the [property, not the attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6004028/1612146).

Since you have the `required` attribute applied to your `<input>` however, you can make use of the `:invalid` pseudo selector:

```
input{
    border:1px solid red;
}
input:invalid {
    border: 1px solid purple;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p0u2e2c3/)

**Documentation**

- [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

Comment: Thanks!! I just want now that when it's in range there is no color. Can i do that?

Comment: In this case, anything that is out of range is seen as invalid, so `:out-of-range` will produce similar results. What do you imagine is valid, but out of range?